# Implementation of Facebook Login Button in Flutter

Tags: facebook, dart, flutter, facebook-login

I think it would be really nice to use Facebook's [newer button SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/#continueas) within my Flutter project. Is there anyway to implement this in Flutter?

(I think this would be a nice feature to add to [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_login)).

Answer (score 2):

I believe (please correct me if I'm wrong), that "Continue as button" is not available on native UI of mobile (Android or iOS) due to the technical implementation / security

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/#8--add-the-facebook-login-button
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/

"Continue as button" is only available in web as your original link reference. Now whether we can go extra miles to have it? I believe so, by using WebView https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter, but as said, "extra miles".